# Как создать копию поля в Tkinter, но с другими координатами?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import copy
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from gtts import gTTS
import sys


CHN_cordX = 130
CHN_cordY = 5

Ru_CordX = 265
Ru_CordY = 5

def app_Run():


    Win = Tk()
    Win.geometry('500x450')
    Convert_Btn = Button(Win,
                         text='Convert',
                         width=10,
                         height=2,
                         bg='gray',
                         fg='black',
                         font='arail 10')
    Convert_Btn.place(x=0, y=3)

    Sort_Btn = Button(Win,
                      text='Sorting',
                      width=10,
                      height=2,
                      bg='gray',
                      fg='black',
                      font='bold 9')
    Sort_Btn.place(x=0, y=50)

    Quantity_Btn_plus = Button(Win,
                               text='十',
                               width=10,
                               height=2,
                               bg='green',
                               fg='white',
                               font='bold 8'
                               )
    Quantity_Btn_plus.place(x=0, y=100)





    Chn_entr = Entry(Win)
    Chn_entr.place(x=CHN_cordX, y=CHN_cordY)


    Ru_Entr = Entry(Win)
    Ru_Entr.place(x=Ru_CordX, y=Ru_CordY)
    LST = {0: Chn_entr,
           1: Ru_Entr}
#Вот тут должна создаваться копия Двух полей ввода, и помещаться ниже на определенное количество пикселей. Как это реализовать ? 
    LST2 = LST.copy

    Quantity_Btn_minus = Button(Win,
                                text='一',
                                width=10,
                                height=2,
                                bg='red',
                                fg='black',
                                font='bold 8',
                                command= LST2 )
    Quantity_Btn_minus.place(x=0, y=150)
    Win.mainloop()
###############################################################################



if __name__ =='__main__':
    app_Run()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы по нажатию одной из кнопок, дублировалась строка ввода, но по другим координатам. Я пытался засунуть строки ввода в словарь, и после копировать словарь, но не знаю как поменять координаты объектов в уже сдублированном словаре. Это сложно объяснить, но как то так...

Comment: Кнопка [+] должна добавлять поля, а кнопка [-] - убирать, так что-ли?

Comment: Да, они должны добавлять пустые поля, для ввода текста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что ж так все любят этот `place()` и пиксели считать? :) Когда оно может само всё размещать.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def app_run():
    entries = []
    
    def add_line(parent):
        frame = Frame(parent)
        frame.pack(fill=X)

        chn_entr = Entry(frame)
        chn_entr.pack(side=LEFT, padx=4, pady=4)

        ru_entr = Entry(frame)
        ru_entr.pack(side=LEFT, padx=4, pady=4)

        entries.append((frame, chn_entr, ru_entr))

    def remove_line():
        if entries:
            frame, *_ = entries.pop()
            frame.destroy()
        
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry('500x450')
    
    frame_btn = Frame(win)
    frame_btn.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=2)
    frame_entries = Frame(win)
    frame_entries.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=2)

    convert_btn = Button(frame_btn,
                         text='Convert',
                         padx=10, pady=10,
                         bg='gray',
                         fg='black',
                         font='arail 10')
    convert_btn.pack(pady=2, fill=X)

    sort_btn = Button(frame_btn,
                      text='Sorting',
                      padx=10, pady=10,
                      bg='gray',
                      fg='black',
                      font='bold 9')
    sort_btn.pack(pady=2, fill=X)

    quantity_btn_plus = Button(frame_btn,
                               text='十',
                               padx=10, pady=10,
                               bg='green',
                               fg='white',
                               font='bold 8',
                               command=lambda: add_line(frame_entries))
    quantity_btn_plus.pack(pady=2, fill=X)

    quantity_btn_minus = Button(frame_btn,
                                text='一',
                                padx=10, pady=10,
                                bg='red',
                                fg='black',
                                font='bold 8',
                                command=remove_line)
    quantity_btn_minus.pack(pady=2, fill=X)

    add_line(frame_entries)
    win.mainloop()


if __name__ =='__main__':
    app_run()
```